# Collision issue with Java Game

Tags: java, collision, bounds, rect, projectile

I am making a little Java Game for practice. Since changing up sprites and what not I am having problems with collision between Enemy and Projectiles. I will provide the Projectile class and can provide more if anyone would like to look! Help would much greatly be appreciated here as I've literally been trying to fix this for hours. Essentially each enemy should take 5 hits then disappear but I can't seem to get it like so. I think the problem lies within the bounds but I really have no idea at the minute what's up.
dn and dn2 are the enemy sprites. r is the projectile fired by my character

```
public class Projectile {

    private int x, y, speedX;
    private boolean visible;
    private Rectangle r;


    public Projectile(int startX, int startY) {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        speedX = 7;
        visible = true;
        r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public void update() {
        x += speedX;
        r.setBounds(x, y, 10, 5);
        if (x > 800) {
            visible = false;
            r = null;
        }
        if (x < 800) {
            checkCollision();
        }
    }

    private void checkCollision() {
        if (r.intersects(StartingClass.dn.r)) {
            visible = false;

            if (StartingClass.dn.health > 0) {
                StartingClass.dn.health -= 1;
            }
            if (StartingClass.dn.health == 0) {
                StartingClass.dn.setCenterX(-100);
                StartingClass.score += 5;

            }
        }

        if (r.intersects(StartingClass.dn2.r)) {
            visible = false;

            if (StartingClass.dn2.health > 0) {
                StartingClass.dn2.health -= 1;
            }
            if (StartingClass.dn2.health == 0) {
                StartingClass.dn2.setCenterX(-100);
                StartingClass.score += 5;

            }
        }

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getSpeedX() {
        return speedX;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
        this.speedX = speedX;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

}

public class Enemy {

private int power, centerX, speedX, centerY;
private Background bg = StartingClass.getBg1();
private Ninja ninja = StartingClass.getNinja();
public static boolean hit = false;

public Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public int health = 5;

private int movementSpeed;

// Behavioral Methods
public void update() {
    follow();
    centerX += speedX;
    speedX = bg.getSpeedX() * 5 + movementSpeed;
    r.setBounds(centerX - 25, centerY - 25, 50, 60);

    if (r.intersects(Ninja.yellowRed)) {
        checkCollision();

    }

}

private void checkCollision() {
    if (r.intersects(Ninja.rect) || r.intersects(Ninja.rect2) || r.intersects(Ninja.rect3) || r.intersects(Ninja.rect4)){
        System.out.println("collision");
        hit = true;
    }
}

public void follow() {

    if (centerX < -95 || centerX > 810) {
        movementSpeed = 0;
    }

    else if (Math.abs(ninja.getCenterX() - centerX) < 5) {
        movementSpeed = 0;
    }

    else {

        if (ninja.getCenterX() >= centerX) {
            movementSpeed = 1;
        } else {
            movementSpeed = -1;
        }
    }

}


public class Ninja {

// Constants are Here
final int JUMPSPEED = -20;
final int MOVESPEED = 5;

private int centerX = 100;
private int centerY = 377;
private boolean jumped = false;
private boolean movingLeft = false;
private boolean movingRight = false;
private boolean ducked = false;
private boolean readyToFire = true;

private int speedX = 0;
private int speedY = 0;
public static Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public static Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public static Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public static Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public static Rectangle yellowRed = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

public static Rectangle footleft = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public static Rectangle footright = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

private Background bg1 = StartingClass.getBg1();
private Background bg2 = StartingClass.getBg2();
public Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

private ArrayList<Projectile> projectiles = new ArrayList<Projectile>();

public void update() {
    // Moves Character or Scrolls Background accordingly.

    if (speedX < 0) {
        centerX += speedX;
    }
    if (speedX == 0 || speedX < 0) {
        bg1.setSpeedX(0);
        bg2.setSpeedX(0);

    }
    if (centerX <= 200 && speedX > 0) {
        centerX += speedX;
    }
    if (speedX > 0 && centerX > 200) {
        bg1.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED / 5);
        bg2.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED / 5);
    }

    // Updates Y Position
    centerY += speedY;

    // Handles Jumping

    speedY += 1;

    if (speedY > 3) {
        jumped = true;
    }

    // Prevents going beyond X coordinate of 0
    if (centerX + speedX <= 60) {
        centerX = 61;
    }

    rect.setRect(centerX - 34, centerY - 30, 67, 62);
    rect2.setRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY() + 63, 68, 63);
    rect3.setRect(rect.getX() - 26, rect.getY() + 32, 26, 20);
    rect4.setRect(rect.getX() + 68, rect.getY() + 32, 26, 20);
    yellowRed.setRect(centerX - 100, centerY - 110, 180, 180);

    footleft.setRect(centerX - 50, centerY + 20, 50, 15);
    footright.setRect(centerX, centerY + 20, 50, 15);

}

public void moveRight() {
    if (ducked == false) {
        speedX = MOVESPEED;
    }
}

public void moveLeft() {
    if (ducked == false) {
        speedX = -MOVESPEED;
    }
}

public void stopRight() {
    setMovingRight(false);
    stop();
}

public void stopLeft() {
    setMovingLeft(false);
    stop();
}

private void stop() {
    if (isMovingRight() == false && isMovingLeft() == false) {
        speedX = 0;
    }

    if (isMovingRight() == false && isMovingLeft() == true) {
        moveLeft();
    }

    if (isMovingRight() == true && isMovingLeft() == false) {
        moveRight();
    }

}

public void jump() {
    if (jumped == false) {
        speedY = JUMPSPEED;
        jumped = true;
    }

}

public void shoot() {
    if (readyToFire) {
        Projectile p = new Projectile(centerX + 40, centerY + 80);
        projectiles.add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code looks ok. Post the code for setting the enemy collision rectangles

Comment: Added 2 new classes there samgak.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved . It lay within my enemy class in r.setBounds(). Just painted that rectangle to screen and adjusted coordinates and all was good